# Function $x/y-y/x$ for complex $x,y$

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I am trying to understand some properties of the function $f(x,y)=x/y-y/x$, where $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$. Does $f$ have a name? I understand that when $|x|=|y|=1$, $\frac{1}{2i}f(x,y)$ measures the sine of the angle between $x$ and $y$, but what is known in general?

Comment: Let's make an important coefficient explicit: if $x=e^{i\theta},\,y=e^{i\phi}$ with $\theta,\,\phi\in\Bbb R$ then $x/y=e^{i(\theta-\phi)}$, so $f=\color{red}{2i}\sin(\theta-\phi)$.

Comment: @J.G. thanks, yes, of course